# Free online service to cut a GIF file

Tags: gratis, web-apps, gif

I am looking for a free online service that can cut a GIF file.

E.g. if the GIF file has a length of 20 seconds, I would like to be able to create a new GIF file that would correspond to the old one from second 5 to 15.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't perfect but [LunaPic](http://lunapic.com/) should do the job.

How to:

- Upload from your computer or enter url to gif. (or use one of the other image provision options - Facebook etc.)
- Select `Animation Menu`->`Edit Gif Animation`
- Select `Animation Ordering / Edit frames`
- Then delete individual frame (*this is the not perfect part* since you can't select a time period to delete them from it would be annoying for long animations. However it is pretty much instant delete with no load between so it isn't deal breaking for most cases.)

You might also want to look at `frame timing` to see the exact timing between frames to know how many to delete.

Comment: The upload button on this site does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Not online but mentioned because it's the only way I could find to remove a range of frames in a single command. For linux, `gifsicle` is a very useful tool:

```
#see how many frames the gif has
gifsicle --info mygif.gif

#delete the last few
gifsicle mygif.gif --delete '#200-' -O3 > out.gif

#or only use a range of frames (doesn't work well for me)
gifsicle -U mygif.gif '#100-200' -O3 > out.gif
```

Note the `-U` "unoptimize" is very important as some gifs use transparency and a bunch of other methods to encode deltas between frames rather than entirely new frames. This would cause artefacts when the original frames are missing. `-O3` re-optimizes the result.

Comment: So much easier than an online tool, even considering the downloading and re-uploading step. Sucks to go through frame by frame, especially if there are hundreds, and choose which ones to keep.